# How to set rubocop case indentation correctly

Tags: ruby, rubocop

How do I get rubo-cop to accept the following as correct for case select:

```
variable = case some_other_variable
  when 'some value' then 'some result'
  when 'some other value' then 'some other result'
  when 'one more value'  then 'one more result'
end
```

I have this currently in my `.rubocop.yml`:

```
CaseIndentation:
  EnforcedStyle: end
  IndentOneStep: true
```

but it keeps erroring like this:

```
C: Layout/CaseIndentation: Indent when one step more than end.
    when 'some value' then 'some result'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says

> - Indent when as deep as case
> - When assigning the result of a conditional expression to a variable,
>     preserve the usual alignment of its branches

So it could be valid for Rubocop this way:

```
variable = case some_other_variable
           when 'some value' then 'some result'
           when 'some other value' then 'some other result'
           when 'one more value' then 'one more result'
           end
```

Or this way

```
variable =
  case some_other_variable
  when 'some value' then 'some result'
  when 'some other value' then 'some other result'
  when 'one more value' then 'one more result'
  end
```

Comment: Maybe so but we want it like it has been displayed in the OP, and I know it should be possible to set it like I want as according to this: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/653#issuecomment-29840347, I just want to know how to do it with current version of rubocop.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask for that in the question? :'-)

Comment: Since that issue is from 2013, and the `IndentWhenRelativeTo` has been renamed to `EnforcedStyle` most probably that options are no longer valid. I couldn't make it work as @jonas054 pointed out.